# "MissingPluginException" en el contexto de Google Maps y Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación Flutter que utiliza el plugin de Google Maps para integrar mapas en mi aplicación. Sin embargo, al ir de la pantalla del mapa a otra pantalla de mi aplicacion, obtengo una excepción 'MissingPluginException'. El mensaje de error completo dice: **'No implementation found for method camera#animate on channel plugins.flutter.dev/google_maps_android_0'**. He verificado que estoy siguiendo las instrucciones de instalación y configuración del plugin, pero todavía enfrento este problema. ¿Qué podría estar causando este error y cómo podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese error es por que al cambiar de pantalla no se pausa tu metodo de animación de camara, ese error lo solucionas poniendo tu metodo de animación en pausa.

Para poder ayudarte mejor podrías mostrar tu código.

Comment: Gracias, tenias razón no pausaba mi metodo. Saludos!

Comment: @LizzullyJacquez un placer, si necesitas mas ayuda no dudes en comentarlo